# WordPress new user email formatting issues

Tags: email, html-email

I have a WordPress site where i have Issue with the email, that user receives after creating an account.

Email that a user receives, looks like this: https://tinyurl.com/y45bgy5z

There is no formatting, no paragraph or no line breaks etc in the email.
I have tried fixing this by adding filter for wp_new_user_notification_email but it did not worked:
I have tried fixing it by using following:

```
add_filter('wp_new_user_notification_email', 'tpkcs_welcome_email', 10, 3);
function tpkcs_welcome_email($wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname)
   {
      $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
      return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
   }
```

I have also tried this:

```
// Add content Type to emial template
function kcss_set_content_type(){
     return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','kcss_set_content_type' );
```

But none of the filters/actions worked either.

Comment: Does it look like this in all email clients? WordPress emails are plain text by default and this looks like the email client just isn't displaying it correctly, which is not a WordPress issue.

Comment: Yes, this is diplayed like this in all email clients. i know be default, wordpress sends plain text email. But i want it to be formatted with like breaks so it can be readable easily

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I finally succeed to display the message with proper line breaks by surrounding the body of the message `$wp_new_user_notification_email['message']`,in your case, with html tags (html, head, body) and filtering it with `nl2br`.

Hope it will help.